# Fullscreen background gif not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image, gif

Currently I am coding a college assignment website. I have a gif for the background of the index page. The gif is fullscreen in both Chrome and Safari but not in firefox.

I know this is because I'm using a width and height of 20%. If I change it to 100%. The is becomes oversized in Chrome and Safari but fits perfectly in Firefox.

I am not sure of what else to try at the moment. I have tried everything I've found on stack overflow about background images but alas nothing is working in all three browsers.

The div is placed above all my content in a div that is opened and closed above all the body content.

CSS:

```
.backgroundgif {
background:url(../images/lettering.gif) no-repeat center center;    
z-index: -1;
width:20%;
height:20%;
position:absolute;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(0.6) brightness(0.7);
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="backgroundgif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scaling only with the `-webkit-` prefix on transform, this is not understood by Firefox.

[The transform property does not really need to be prefixed for anything other than Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform). Add the non prefixed property as well.

To prevent any scrolling issues, use `position: fixed` instead. It will not scroll.

```css
.backgroundgif {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/1000) no-repeat center center;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(0.6) brightness(0.7);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundgif">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I didn't realise that the transform property doesn't need to be indexed.